# Characterisations of Markov Processes: SDE's , Generators,...

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

There are different characterisations of a Markov Process: Probability Semigroups, Generators, even in some cases by Jumps Chains and Holding Times...
And I know that, in "real life", the only thing one has is a Stochastic Differential Equation with a Markovian Behaviour...

My questions are:

1) Is the latter the most frequent or which one is the most common when dealing with real-models?

2) which is the relationship between the
 "SDE characterisation" and the rest? ( or where I can find information about it?). I'm trying know if there is any general presentation of a Markov Process as a solution of an SDE, and in which cases there is a correspondence between this characterisation and any of the other.

I don't know if it helps, but I'm dealing with a process like this:

> \begin{equation} \begin{split} dX_i(t) = - X_i(t)dt & + \sum_{j \neq
>  i} \int_{R_+^2} z_i \mathbb{1}_{\{ 0 \leq u \leq b(X_j(t-))\}}
>  \mathcal{N}_j (du,dz,dt) \\
>                       & - X_i(t^-)\int_{R_+^2} \mathbb{1}_{\{ 0 \leq u \leq b(X_i(t-))\}} \mathcal{N}_i (du,dz,dt) \end{split} \end{equation}
>    Where $(\mathcal{N}_j)$ are independent Poisson Processes with
>    intensity measure  $du\bigotimes \mathbb{W}^j(dz)\bigotimes dt $, with
>    \begin{equation} \mathbb{W}^j (dz) = \bigotimes _{k = 1} ^{j-1}
>  W(dz_k) \bigotimes \delta_0(dz_j)\bigotimes_{k=j+1}^N W(dz_k) 
> \end{equation}

$W(dx)$ non-negative, integrable and $b:R_+ \to R_+$ is $C^1$, non-decreasing.

Comment: By "Markov chain" are you including general Markov processes which may take values in an uncountable state space (for example, Feller processes)?

Comment: @Math1000 that's right! I meant "Mrkov, Process" I will edit that, thank you.

Comment: Re 2): Could you elaborate which kind of information you are looking for?

Comment: @saz  I've edited my question!

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it later.